# Paste into RichTextBox results duplicate paste

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, paste

I have a copy button in vb.net (RTBDocPanel), that copy text from a RichTextBox, as:

```
'Copia la selección
Private Sub ToolStripButtonCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButtonCopy.Click

    Clipboard.Clear()
    Clipboard.SetText(RTBdocPanel.SelectedRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf)

End Sub
```

After this, I tried to paste as:

```
'Pega selección
Private Sub PegarSeleccion()

    Dim iData As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

    'Pega el texto si es texto, RTF si es RTF
    If iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
        RTBdocPanel.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
    ElseIf iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf) Then
        RTBdocPanel.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString
    End If

End Sub
```

But result is a duplicate formatted text (for example, copy "Hello", paste "HelloHello")

I can't find the mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You issues isn't apparent to me, I've also tried your code and cannot get anything to happen outside what I expect to happen. I copy selected text in the box and can copy it. The only way I could get your result is to type Hello, select it, copy it, then immediately paste. This puts the paste immediately after the original Hello I copied. Are you instead wanting to Cut which would remove the original?

Comment: Hello Charles. Thanks in advance for your interest. No, I have also. Cut button in my form. The problem appears at pasting anywhere.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot duplicate the issue. Is there something going on around the code that calls your PegarSeleccion() method? I would also maybe suggest a breakpoint at the start of this sub and see if somehow it's being called twice as that would produce your result.

Comment: Hey Charles, I finally found the mistake (really two mistakes), but they were not in that part of the code (sorry for that):

1. In the Ctrl+V operation, the  - If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then - was written with "AndAlso" instead "And"

2. It means better idea put the Ctrl+V in KeyUp instead KeiDown event.

Anyway, thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: In case this is not just a learning exercise, I have to ask why are you replicating functionality that the WinForm RTB already exposes for Cut/Copy/Paste?  Also as long as `ShortCutsEnabled=True`, there is no need to interpret Ctrl+V and other standard keyboard shortcuts.